# ios 8.3 BLE Device keeps disconnecting after connecting objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I have a Shearwell stick reader, which reads in cattle tags, sheep tags and goat tags via BLE. When connecting the BLE device, the device list shows up in the tableView of the SDLBluetoothConnectViewController then disappears. I am also not able to grab the information from the device using a segue. The bluetooth icon flashes 3 times and does not pair with the device. Can anyone see where my error is i've looked for hours!! thanks in advance!

here is the SDLStickreader.m

```
 // A StickReader is a wrapper for a CBPeripheral that has been discovered using a filter for StickReader UUID.
#import "SDLStickReader.h"
#import "SDLStickReaderManager.h"
#import "SDLStickReaderPrivate.h"
#import "SDLSerialPort.h"
//#import "SDLIdentifier.h"

@interface SDLStickReader () <SerialPortDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheral *peripheral;
@end

@implementation SDLStickReader

static SDLStickReaderManager * _manager;
NSMutableData *_data;
SDLSerialPort *serialPort;
BOOL waitingForConfigInfo = YES;
NSMutableString *configString;


+(SDLStickReaderManager *)manager {
if (nil == _manager) {
    _manager = [[SDLStickReaderManager alloc] init];


}
return _manager;
}

+ (instancetype)forPeripheral: (CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
return [[self alloc] initWithPeripheral:peripheral];
}

- (instancetype)initWithPeripheral: (CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    _detail = @"";
    self.peripheral = peripheral;
    //peripheral.delegate = self;
    __tagReadService = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:SDL_STICKREADER_TAGREAD_UUID];
            if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) {
                NSLog(@"periperal is connected");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"periperal is NOT connected");
            }
    _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    serialPort = [[SDLSerialPort alloc] initWithPeripheral:peripheral     andDelegate:self];
    peripheral.delegate = self;
    [serialPort open ];

    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)hasPeripheral: (CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
return [self.peripheral isEqual: peripheral];
}

-(NSUUID *)identifier {
return self.peripheral.identifier;
}

-(NSString *)name {
return self.peripheral.name;
}

-(NSString *)description {
return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Peripheral: %@", self.name];
}

-(NSString *)state {
switch (self.peripheral.state) {
    case CBPeripheralStateConnected:
        return SDL_STICKREADER_STATE_CONNECTED;
    case CBPeripheralStateConnecting:
        return SDL_STICKREADER_STATE_CONNECTING;
    case CBPeripheralStateDisconnected:
        return SDL_STICKREADER_STATE_DISCONNECTED;
 }
}
// Every time the peripheral sends new data, it calls the delegate         peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error: method. The second argument     contains the characteristic that you can read.
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:    (CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error");
    return;
}
if ([self.characteristics containsObject: characteristic.UUID]) {
    NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc]     initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // Have we got everything we need?
    NSUInteger startOfEom = [stringFromData rangeOfString:     SDL_STICKREADER_EOM].location;
    if (NSNotFound == startOfEom) {
        // it is not the EOM so append the data to what we have so far and     wait for more.
        [_data appendData: characteristic.value];
    } else {
        // contains EOM, so remove the
        NSString *lastPart = [stringFromData substringToIndex:startOfEom];
        NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: _data     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (nil != lastPart && lastPart.length > 0) {
            message = [message stringByAppendingString:lastPart];
        }
        if (nil != self.listener) {
            [self.listener stickReader:self didReadTag:message];
        }
        [_data setLength:0];
    }
 }
}

// Method that ensures that the CBCentral knows when a notification state for a given characteristic changes. Track it in order to understand when a characteristic state changes (update app values). You should check if the characteristic notification has stopped. If it has, you should disconnect from it:
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {

if (![self.characteristics containsObject: characteristic.UUID]) {
    return;
}

if (characteristic.isNotifying) {
    NSLog(@"Notification began ");
} else {
    // Notification has stopped
    NSLog(@"Notification stopped ");
    //[_manager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];
}
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void) port: (SDLSerialPort*) serialPort event : (SPEvent) ev error: (NSInteger)err {
if (SP_EVT_OPEN == ev) {
    //NSLog(@"serialPortOpened");
    configString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    [serialPort write: [@"c\r" dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
} else {
    NSLog(@"serialPortClosed");
 }
}

- (void) writeComplete: (SDLSerialPort*) serialPort withError: (NSInteger)err     {
NSLog(@"writeComplete");
}

- (void) port: (SDLSerialPort*) serialPort receivedData: (NSData*)data {

if (data.length > 0) {
    NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet     characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"|()#"];


    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding:     NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"receivedData: %@", str);
    if ([str hasPrefix: @"Shearwell"]) {
        _detail = str;
        //NSLog(@"updating: %@", str);

        [[SDLStickReader manager] addedShearwellStickReader: self];
    } else if (NSNotFound != [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet: charSet].location )     {
        // Data
        if (waitingForConfigInfo) {
            [configString appendString:str];
            if (NSNotFound != [configString rangeOfString: @"(cS)"].location)     {
                // got end of config string, parse config.
                NSRange found = [configString rangeOfString: @"#18|"];
                if (NSNotFound != found.location) {
                    NSRange getRange = NSMakeRange(found.location +     found.length, 1);
                    NSString *str = [configString substringWithRange:     getRange];
                    self.eidFormat = [str integerValue];
                    NSLog(@"StickReader format: %d", self.eidFormat); 
                }
                waitingForConfigInfo = NO;
                [serialPort write: [@"v\r" dataUsingEncoding:     NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            }
        } else {
            // Users data
            [self.listener stickReader:self didReadData: str];
        }
    } else {
        // Tag
        if (nil != self.listener) {
            [self.listener stickReader:self didReadTag: str];
        }
    }
}
}
```

and my SDLBluetoothConnectViewController.m

```
#import "SDLBluetoothConnectViewController.h"
#import "SDLStickReaderManager.h"
#import "SDLStickReader.h"
#import "SDLViewController.h"


@interface SDLBluetoothConnectViewController () <UITableViewDataSource,     UITableViewDelegate, SDLStickReaderManagerListener>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *stickReaderListView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *stickReaderNameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *stickReaderDescLabel;

@end

/*
 This class starts the process of scanning in the 'viewDidLoad' method by setting the SDLStickReaderManager 'singleton' to self.  When the scan button is pressed the SDLStickReaderManager scan is called, and each stick reader found is returned via the listener call.  This listener call is used to refresh the table view.

 When a user selects a stick reader from the list the StickReader view is started and passed the selected stick reader.
 */
@implementation SDLBluetoothConnectViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[self.stickReaderListView setDelegate: self];
[self.stickReaderListView setDataSource: self];
[SDLStickReader manager].listener = self;
[self.stickReaderListView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)scanButtonPressed:(id)sender {
[SDLStickReader.manager scan];
}

- (IBAction)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender {
SDLStickReader.manager.listener = nil;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
/*
 Every time the view disappears, you should stop the scanning process.
 */
[SDLStickReader.manager stopScan];
}

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////// Table handling     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


NSArray *stickReaders = SDLStickReader.manager.discoveredStickReaders;
SDLStickReader * stickReader = [stickReaders  objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];


[SDLStickReader.manager stopScan];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"deviceInfoSegue" sender:self];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSArray *stickReaders = SDLStickReader.manager.discoveredStickReaders;
return stickReaders.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString * simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier];
if (nil == cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier];
}
NSArray *stickReaders = SDLStickReader.manager.discoveredStickReaders;
SDLStickReader * stickReader = [stickReaders  objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
NSString *desc = [stickReader name];
cell.textLabel.text = desc;
return cell;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"deviceInfoSegue"]) {
    //some additional info here 
}

}


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    /
/// SDLStickReaderManager callbacks     ///////////////////////////////////////////////

-(void)stickReader: (SDLStickReader *)stickReader addedToList: (NSArray *)discoveredStickReaders {
//NSLog(@"View StickReaderAdded");
[self.stickReaderListView reloadData];
//[SDLStickReader.manager connect: stickReader];
}

-(void)connectedStickReader: (SDLStickReader *)stickReader {
//NSLog(@"View StickReader connected");
[self.stickReaderListView reloadData];
}

-(void)disconnectedStickReader: (SDLStickReader *)stickReader {
//NSLog(@"View StickReader disconnected");
[self.stickReaderListView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Hi Tyron! I have the same issue. It only happens on iOS 8.3. Did you eventually find a solution?

Comment: HI Fervus, It seems to be only the iphone 5 at the moment. Have tested with the iphone 4s and iPad 3,4 and those devices seem to connect correctly. I am going directly to the manufacturer of the SDLStickReader to get a fix for this issue. Sorry I couldn't be of more help! Good luck! :)

Comment: For me it happens on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6, but I am connecting to a ConnectBlue OBS421 device. It worked fine until iOS 8.3. I've also contacted the manufacturer to see if they have any clues but I'm yet to receive an answer. Thanks!